# VS 2015 doesn't start up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried re-installing twice and removed all the regedit entries it had earlier & rebooted the machine. Even after doing all this stuff, it just won't start up. I am on this screen for the past 3hours. Can somebody give me a fix?

[image: This is the screen print]

Answer (score 0):

you can try performing the following command line operations

devenv /ResetSettings

or

devenv /resetuserdata

You can also try to run Visual Studio in safe mode, obviously it does not fix the problem but it could be a starting point for the investigation

devenv.exe  /SafeMode

Comment: I tried both the options .I still see the same white screen.

Comment: Did you try also running it in safe mode?

Comment: yes, I tried running it in safe mode too. I tried debug option as well to check I can find something but nothing comes up. This is a weird error I am seeing in 4years of usage.